# Error When Passing Struct as Input to Function in Solidity

Tags: remix, struct, function

I'm trying to just call a function that has a struct argument...The thing is that Remix somehow doesn't recognize all the inputs from the struct in the function.
I tried making the image very descriptive! It contains the struct, it contains the argument I'm passing in and it contains the values array that shows all the correct arguments, expect for one, where it replaces "2027" with "," and so I can't move forward with the transaction.
I tried all combinations of commas in between the arguments, like all of the arguments with a whitespace after them or before them, a space after and before them, etc. If the image is too small, just click on it.

[image]

```
mapping(uint16 => Plot[]) plotsInFlorest;
function createAPlot(
uint8 _correspondingFlorest,
Plot memory plot
) external 
{
   Plot storage ploT = plotsInFlorest[_correspondingFlorest][plotId];
   ploT.localization = plot.localization; //string
   ploT.plotAge = plot.plotAge; //uint16
   ploT.plotPlantingYear = plot.plotPlantingYear; //uint16
   ploT.plotCutYear = plot.plotCutYear; //uint16
   ploT.woodTypeForPlot = plot.woodTypeForPlot; //enum of two elements
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter for struct should be passed in the form of tupple or array. In remix put Plot struct params in the form of tupple.

eg.

```
["local",7,2020,2027,0]
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked! The tx went through but gave the following error though: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: In that case I have to see the code.

Comment: no problem, I updated the question with the function that's throwing the error when called with those arguments...Thanks!

Comment: Also added the mapping I'm using the in the function